# Illegal characters in URI

Tags: java, url, encoding, utf

The `java.net.URI` ctor accepts *most* non-ASCII characters but does not accept  [ideographic space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) (0x3000). The ctor fails with `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path ...`

So my questions are:

- Why doesn't the `URI` ctor accept `0x3000` but does accept other non-ASCII characters ?
- What other characters doesn't it accept ?

Comment: It says on your source: "Do not use this character in domain names. Browsers are blacklisting it because of the potential for phishing."

Comment: It is _not_ used in _domain names_. It is used in other parts of `URI`.

Comment: It is probable that it has been blacklisted since URI can contain web addresses.

Comment: This contradicts both what the URI javadoc says, and my reading of the source code.  Please provide an SSCCE that demonstrates the failure that you are talking about.

Comment: @StephenC try  `new Url("http://myhost.com/かんぽの宿 　坂出")` and `new Url("http://myhost.com/かんぽの宿坂出")`. Please note the 1st example contains the _ideographic space_ rather than a regular space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please note the 1st example contains the ideographic space rather than a regular space.

It is the ideographic space that is the problem.

Here is the code that allows non-ASCII characters to be used:

```
        } else if ((c > 128)
                   && !Character.isSpaceChar(c)
                   && !Character.isISOControl(c)) {
            // Allow unescaped but visible non-US-ASCII chars
            return p + 1;
        }
```

As you can see, it disallows "funky" non-visible characters.

See also the `URI` class [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) which specifies which characters are allowed (by the class!) in each component of a URI.

> Why?

It is probably a safety measure.

> What others are disallowed?

An character that is whitespace or a control character ... according to the respective `Character` predicate methods.  (See the `Character` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for a precise specification.)

You should also note that this is a **deviation** from the URI specification.  The URI specification says that non-ASCII characters are only allowed if you:

- convert the UCS character code to UTF-8, and
- percent encode the UTF-8 bytes as required by the spec.

My understanding is that the `URI.toASCIIString()` method will take care of that if you have a "deviant" `java.net.URI` object.

Answer (score 4):

The set of acceptable characters is spelled out in detail in the [JavaDoc documentation for `java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

> ### Character categories
>
> RFC 2396 specifies precisely which characters are permitted in the various components of a URI reference. The following categories, most of which are taken from that specification, are used below to describe these constraints:
>
> - **alpha**   The US-ASCII alphabetic characters, 'A' through 'Z' and 'a' through 'z'
> - **digit**   The US-ASCII decimal digit characters, '0' through '9'
> - **alphanum**    All alpha and digit characters
>     unreserved      All alphanum characters together with those in the string "_-!.~'()*"
> - **punct**   The characters in the string ",;:$&+="
> - **reserved**    All punct characters together with those in the string "?/[]@"
> - **escaped** Escaped octets, that is, triplets consisting of the percent character ('%') followed by two hexadecimal digits ('0'-'9', 'A'-'F', and 'a'-'f')
> - **other**   The Unicode characters that are not in the US-ASCII character set, are not control characters (according to the `Character.isISOControl` method), and are not space characters (according to the `Character.isSpaceChar` method)  (Deviation from RFC 2396, which is limited to US-ASCII)
>
> The set of all legal URI characters consists of the unreserved, reserved, escaped, and other characters.

In particular, "other" does *not* include space characters, which are defined (by Character.isSpaceChar) as those with Unicode general category types

- SPACE_SEPARATOR
- LINE_SEPARATOR
- PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR

and according to the page you've linked to in the question, the ideographic space character is indeed one of these types.

Comment: @Michael you asked about the rules for `java.net.URI`, not `URL`, they're different.

Comment: Sorry. I meant `new java.net.URI("http://myhost.com/かんぽの宿坂出")`. Just try it and see does not fail

Comment: @Michael yes, that looks to be consistent with the rules I quoted in my answer - those ideographs are characters that are not in the US-ASCII character set, are not control characters, and are not space characters, so they qualify as "other".